# Turn off --skip-grant-tables in MySQL

Tags: linux, terminal, mysql, amazon-ec2

I'm pretty new to using Linux but am setting up my MySQL databases on an Amazon ec2 instance. I followed some directions I found about resetting the user login pass by using the `--skip-grant-tables` option of MySQL. Now I am trying to add a user and can't figure out how to turn that option off.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
mysql> GRANT CREATE,SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE ON ...my db username and pass
```

but I get this error:

```
ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement
```

How do I turn this option off?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just stop and restart MySQL normally.

Answer (score 44):

Login to mysql

```
 mysql -u root -p
```

Then execute:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-options.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqladmin.html

Answer (score 6):

You can make this done by using below steps.

```
[root@backups1 mysql5.7]# bin/mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --user=mysql
```

connect to your mysql without password.

```
mysql> flush privileges;
mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '';
mysql> flush privileges;
```

switch to normal mode of mysql then connect without password.

This surely will work for you.

Comment: Doesn't work with mariadb.

Answer (score 2):

Slight modifications from @mansur ali

MYSQL 8, Ubuntu 18.04

```
[ubuntu@ip-172-31-39-173]$  sudo /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --user=mysql
```

connect to your mysql without password in another shell by executing

```
$ mysql
```

then

```
mysql> flush privileges;
mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '';
mysql> flush privileges;
mysql> quit;
```

switch to normal mode of mysql then connect without password.

This surely will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Yesterday I've encountered similar issue.  The server was using Amazon Linux 2 as OS and the official yum repository (the el7 ones) as the installation means.

Especially when you are using the MySQL of the official yum repo, MySQL would be installed as a systemd service.  In such case, you can check how MySQL process is launched by executing following command: `sudo service mysql status -l`.  This results in description of the current status of the current mysql service.  Of those descriptions, I could find following line:

```
  Process: 26474 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid $MYSQLD_OPTS
```

In my environment, it turned out that the `MYSQLD_OPTS` variable was set with value `--skip-grant-tables` option by the systemd process.  To confirm the environment variables set by systemd, you can execute `sudo systemctl show` and look for line starting with `Environment=`.

To change this environment variable, I executed following command.

```
sudo systemctl set-environment MYSQLD_OPTS=""
```

After this operation, I restarted the mysqld service by `sudo service mysql restart`, and everything was working perfectly.